# About Local homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:(X,T_{X}) \to (Y,T_{Y})$ be a map between two topological spaces such that
$f(T_{X}) \subset T_{Y}$ and $f^{-1}(T_{Y}) \subset T_{X}$
then f is local homeomorphism?

Motivation: We have some types map in topological category for example: open map, continuous map , local homeomorphism map , homeomorphism map, quatient map, proper map, covering map and...
I think about these map and i try classify all of type map in unique way, and some questions rise such above question. We see homeomorphism is continuous and open map that also bijective, if we remove condition bijectivity we obtain a map define in above question, so this kind map is the closest type map to homeomorphism, also local homeomorphism is close to homeomorphism , if fact both of them with assumption bijectivity are homeomorphism, I guess this kind map in question must be local homeomorphis, is this two type map is equivalent? there is sutible condition? if we consider standard topology(mean that I have good properties on topology like Hausdorff, second countable , ..) then question is true? what is different two type map?

Comment: Please [avoid "no-clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/29298#29298).

Comment: @AnneBauval thanks , will be observed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Denote by $T_1$ the discrete topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and $T_2$ the indiscrete topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Consider

$$ f: (\mathbb{R}, T_2) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, T_1), x\mapsto 0. $$

This is not a local homeomorphism, but clearly it satisfies your requirement. In fact, there is not a single point around which this map is a local homeomorphism (in order to render the map injective, we would need to choose a singleton, however, this is not an open set in the indiscrete topology).

**Added:** Let me give a proof that my example really works. Pick any set $U\in \mathbb{R}$. If $0\in U$, then $f^{-1}(U)=\mathbb{R}$ and if $0\notin U$, then $f^{-1}(U)=\emptyset$. You see that you can replace both $T_1,T_2$ with any topology and we would still have $f^{-1}(T_1)\subseteq T_2$. The only thing I need is that $\{0\}\in T_1$ to ensure $f(T_2)=\{\{0\}, \emptyset\}\subseteq T_1$.

This also shows that we can get counterexamples for very nice topological spaces. For example we can consider

$$ g:(X,T_X)\rightarrow (\{0,1\}, \mathcal{P}(\{0,1\})), g(x)=0,$$
where $(X,T_X)$ is any topological space. Also the codomain is a finite metric space, which is as nice as it gets.

**Added even later:** The class mentioned in the OP consists of all maps that are open and continuous. Thus, the local homeomorphism are a strict subclass. Namely, a map in the class of the OP is a local homeomorphism iff it is locally injective.

Comment: @AnneBauval I generally agree with you (as you can see from my comments on a representation theory question I posted couple of minutes ago). For this question I could just not resist, it is exactly the type I like. I hope people can forgive me this guilty pleasure for once :)

Comment: @AnneBauval The problem with the comment is that people then complain about the answer and about answering as a comment (I got scolded/kindly asked to write up my comments as an answer already a couple of times). Restraining oneself would be the correct choice.

Comment: I did not quite understand your last comment. What are "standard topologies"? Also the rest is not clear to me. Are you looking for specific conditions to get local homeomorphisms? I mean really the problem is not anything about the topology, it is about being injective in a neighborhood of the point. Your condition is telling me that if we restrict our map to any open set, then the map is still open and continuous, so we just need to worry about getting injectivity on some open set around a given point.

Comment: I lost my comment when i want edit it, i revised my question and give some motivation. thnks to you for counter example. Standard topology , I means we have some natural property for it, like Hausdorff or Second countable like this @Severin

Comment: It seems that your example is not true, becuase $f^{-1}(T_{1})$ is not subset of $T_{2}$ in general.

Comment: @Deliasaghi Constant maps are always continuous. I have added a proof in my post.

Comment: You are right, thanks for detail. With your example, we can conclude that local homeomorphism is closer to homeomorphism respect to our type map in question.

Comment: In fact the converse of my statement is true.

Comment: @Deliasaghi Your class strictly contains the local homeomorphisms. In fact a map is a local homeomorphism iff it is in your class and locally injective (your class is really just all maps that are open and continuous).

Comment: You are right, thanks.